# Writing into a file then reading it on Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, file

```
target=open("test.txt",'w+')
target.write('ffff')
print(target.read())
```

When running the following python script (test.txt is an empty file), it prints an empty string.

However, when reopening the file, it can read it just fine:

```
target=open("test.txt",'w+')
target.write('ffff')
target=open("test.txt",'r')
print(target.read())
```

This prints out 'ffff' as needed.

Why is this happening? Is 'target' still recognized as having no content, even though I updated it in line 2, and I have to reassign test.txt to it?

Comment: you're forgetting to `close()` the file. that will flush the data into the file.

Comment: that or you have to rewind the file. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: what has flushing got to do with this? It's the same file object, same file handle, same process. Reading will find the data in the buffer if needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters corrected in the second comment. But it's not clear what OP is trying to do. close and read or rewind and read.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: they expected to be able to read the data they have written to the file, without reopening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A file has a read/write position. Writing to the file puts that position at the end of the written text; reading starts from the same position.

Put that position back to the start with the [`seek` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek):

```
with open("test.txt",'w+') as target:
    target.write('ffff')
    target.seek(0)  # to the start again
    print(target.read())
```

Demo:

```
>>> with open("test.txt",'w+') as target:
...     target.write('ffff')
...     target.seek(0)  # to the start again
...     print(target.read())
...
4
0
ffff
```

The numbers are the return values of `target.write()` and `target.seek()`; they are the number of characters written, and the new position.

Answer (score 4):

No need to close and re-open it. You just need to seek back to the file's starting point before reading it:

```
with open("test.txt",'w+') as f:
    f.write('ffff')
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing, then seeking the beginning of the file:

```
f = open(path, 'w+')
f.write('foo')
f.write('bar')
f.flush()
f.seek(0)
print(f.read())
```

Comment: Flushing is *not needed*. This is the same process, same file handle.

Answer (score -1):

you have to `close()` the file before reading it. You cannot read and write to a file at the same time. this causes inconsistency.

Comment: This is patent nonsense. The file I/O layer knows how to read from the buffer too. All you need to do is understand file positions.